# Error creating bean with name 'passwordEncoder': Requested bean is currently in creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lazy-loading

I have a issue when I try to start Spring Boot project:

```
11:32:32.609 [main] DEBUG AnnotationConfigApplicationContext[doClose:1006] - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@258e2e41, started on Thu Jul 16 11:32:17 EEST 2020
11:32:32.623 [main] ERROR SpringApplication[reportFailure:837] - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/plte1219/Desktop/CJM/OAuth2/target/engine-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/org/engine/rest/UsersController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 7; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/plte1219/Desktop/CJM/OAuth2/target/engine-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/org/engine/security/OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'passwordEncoder': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
        at org.engine.EngineApplication.main(EngineApplication.java:13)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/plte1219/Desktop/CJM/OAuth2/target/engine-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/org/engine/security/OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'passwordEncoder': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:408)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1224)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'passwordEncoder': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:347)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:219)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1224)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)
        ... 51 common frames omitted
```

I managed to fix the issue using `@Lazy` annotation adding it in these places:

[Guthub link 1](https://github.com/rcbandit111/OAuth2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/security/OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt.java#L50)
[Github link 2](https://github.com/rcbandit111/OAuth2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/security/WebSecurityConfig.java#L26)

I want to fix the issue without using `@Lazy` loading. Do you know how I can restructure the code in order to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring context is trying to create your UserController bean. To create UserController it needs to create all its dependencies among which there are two that depends on each other.

UserController depends on OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt which depends on PasswordEncoder. At the same time UserController also depends on PasswordEncoder. That's why Spring cannot create UserController bean.

To solve this issue you need carefully manage your dependencies to prevent such situations.

In current situation you can remove PasswordEncoder from UserController. Add getter for it in OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt and receive this dependency in controller through OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt.

This is the easiest solution if not to dig deeply into the code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Just for information is there any better solution that you can think of?

Comment: I took a look into the code more deeply. Your OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt waiting for injection PasswordEncoder but this bean is defined in OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt. So to create OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt you need PasswordEncoder, but to create PasswordEncoder you need OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt. So this is cyclic dependency that could not be resolved by Spring. You should remove PasswordEncoder from constructor of OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt and use passwordEncoder method instead or inject it by method injection

Comment: Hm... looks like the solution is much more simple after I played with the code: I moved the bean `BCryptPasswordEncoder` into new Java class with annotation `@Configuration` and now it's working fine. I don't know is this a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

from spring-boot-starter 2.6 onwards , there is new breaking change introduced, to resolve the circular dependency issue, Please add below property in application.properties.
spring.main.allow-circular-references = true

Please check below link for more.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#upgrading-from-spring-boot-25